# Which floor is likely to collapse during the earthquake?

Tags: structural-engineering

I'm currently working on resonance frequencies of buildings and have to do a practical work/experiment on which floor of the building is likely to collapse during the earthquake. I have the slight idea on how it will work but I have no idea how I should do an experiment to show and prove it. My guess is the top floor as it will move more distance in same time (therefore move faster) and it is higher than the center of the gravity.

I have quite a variety of apparatus such as the amplifier, signal generator, arbitrary function generator, vibration generator, sliding platforms and some metal plates for building structures.

It would be great if I can get some insights and tips on how I should go about doing the experiment. Some equations relating to thus would be great.

Comment: When you say "which floor will collapse", are you expecting a floor to collapse while leaving the columns intact, or are you expecting the building to collapse from a certain floor upwards?

Comment: That's not how buildings work.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft thanks for thr answer. It wasn't me who made up this question so I am just as confused as you are.

Comment: I would guess that the 2nd floor is likely to collapse first. The two reasons for this are that all the motion is in the ground floor (and thus the displacement) and all the weight of the upper floors is resting on the second floor). But I'm no earthquake engineer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty big topic but to point you in the right direction: start by having a read of the Wikipedia article on [Seismic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_analysis). There you will see there are different methods of analysis with increasing complexity.

**Answering your question**: to predict failure at a certain floor I would suggest carrying out a response spectrum analysis (modal analysis with lumped mass model) which will give you displacements at each floor for a given input signal frequency. Note that failure will not necessarily occur at the floor with the largest absolute displacement but at that with the largest inter-floor drift (the largest displacement relative to the floor beneath it). You can then re-run this analysis with a range of input frequencies until you find one where it is very clear which floor is most likely to fail.

As far as equations go, the above approach involves solving a system of harmonic equations treating each floor as a mass with a [damped harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator). The system is then excited by an arbitrary forcing function, $\mathbf{F}(t)$, from your signal generator:
$$
\mathbf{F}(t) = M\ddot{\mathbf{x}} + C\dot{\mathbf{x}} + K\mathbf{x}
$$
Where:

$M$ is your lumped mass matrix (one entry per line representing floor weight)

$C$ is your damping matrix (represents damping force on each floor related to velocities of the floors either side)

$K$ is the spring force matrix (representing spring force on each floor related to relative displacement of the floors either side)